# How to submit formdata to ASP.NET Core MVC action using JQuery Ajax in a dynamic created form

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-3.1

I have made a Form that contains a `UL` with `li` where each `li` contains inputs and a multiple file form type input, first I load a single row from a predefined HTML document. then I take as reference one of the li to create another similar, one contrains a input with file type with a multiple property. Then I have a submit button that `onclick` goes to `SendProducts` that iterates through each input type on each `li` and store the data in a `FormData` object each named respectively as if they were a part of a `List<Products>` in the MVC pattern. The Model contains a `IEnumerable<IFormFile>` when I try to post it doesn't go to the action and just refreshed the page

I am using ASP.NET Core 5.02

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/file-uploads?view=aspnetcore-5.0#match-name-attribute-value-to-parameter-name-of-post-method

the solution is matching the field's name on the FormData assigned key? name you could set it as

```
myFormData.append("products["+(overallObjectCount)+"].Files", inputControl.files[i], inputControl.files[i].name);
```

if the action's parameter is called Listproducts and contain a

```
List<IFormFile> {get;set;} = new List<IFormFile>();
```